# How to use grouped_collection_select in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have School and Course models as follows:

```html
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :school
end

                                 
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :courses
  
end
```

And I want to create select with course options grouped by schools. I try this:

```html
<%= grouped_collection_select(:course,:school_id,School.all,Course.all,:name,:id,:name) %>
```

I read Rails API dock, but still can't figure it out.

EDIT: This is what i need:

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="School1">
    <option value="1">Course1</option>
  </optgroup>
  ..etc
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to create select with course options grouped by schools" ?

Comment: @Pavan, i edited my question

Comment: where do you see two collections in api-dock ? I see only one http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Comment: @alkuzad, oh yes, i just misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, i just misunderstood difference between collection and group_method:

Parameters:

1) model for which to use select

2) foreign_key in the model (course)

3) collection to populate select

4) method for grouping (here we group by :course)

5) label for optiongroup

6) value for select option

7) value for select option

```
<%=grouped_collection_select(:course,:school_id,School.all,:courses,:name,:id,:name) %>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.